# Read only group can add documents/items

Tags: document-library, read-only

My read only OOB group can add items to document libraries and issue tracker lists. Can anyone help me turn this off? I have looked everywhere and I am stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Your Users in read Only Group(Visitor) might be in another group like "Members" or "Owner"...
Just confirm that users in Read Only group(Visitor) are not in any other group..

Answer (score 0):

You can check the users' permissions from `[SPSITE]/_layouts/chkperm.aspx`. It should show all the groups the users belong to and all the permissions they have.